# What is the meaning of exponential term in the given model?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology, delay-differential-equations

[image: Infection Dynamics]

l1, l2,l3,s are different classes and parasites are moving from one class to other. I am not getting why author used exponential term in the model? 
Could you please tell the meaning of exponential term.
thanks :)

Comment: It is used because it is the result of a derivative of the function $I_2(t)$. We don't know the explicit formula for this function from what you have shown here.

Answer (score 0):

As NoChance comments, without more details about the model formulation, it is difficult to give an answer. However, I speculate that the $l$ and $s$ are formulated using integral equations and the exponential part is related to the amount of time the parasites stay in a certain class. For example, see page 13 of https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30674119.